# I want to pass multiple variables into another php page using an href in an anchor tag

Tags: php

I have this  code in my page1.php which passes 2 variables.(im using pdo btw)

```
<a type="button" href="PT-ContractsInfo.php?id=<?php echo $pt['TL_Code']?>&amp;client=<?php echo $pt['CLIENT_ID']?>" class="btn bg-green" >View</a>
```

...And my code for page2.php

```
    <?php
       $id = $_GET['id'];
       $client = $_GET['client'];
    <?
```

But it outputs an error "Undefined index: client"...
Is there something wrong with the codes?Ty

Comment: How is `PDO` related here?

Comment: You're linking to `PT-ContractsInfo.php` and not `page2.php`

Comment: Also `type="button"` is not valid for `<a>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0):

you have semicolon missing

```
<?php echo $pt['TL_Code']?>
```

should be

```
<?php echo $pt['TL_Code']; ?>
```

but anyways you want to be careful when echoing variables in an url, you should encode the variable in url format first

like

`<?php echo urlencode( $pt['TL_Code'] ); ?>`

you can also use `http_build_query()` which would be even cleaner

Comment: sorry, I mean semicolon, the ";" character